# Add user to owner group from High Trust App (user + app policy)

Tags: 2013, provider-hosted-app, csom, high-trust-app

I have an High Trust Provider Hosted App, which is using App + User policy

[User - ManageWeb/Owner and App - Full Control]

```
        Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(oWebsite);

        Group group = oWebsite.SiteGroups.GetByName("Home Owners");
        clientContext.Load(group, grp => grp.Users);

        UserCreationInformation userCreationInfo = new UserCreationInformation();
        userCreationInfo.Email = "kkb@dev.com";
        userCreationInfo.LoginName = @"dev\kkb";
        userCreationInfo.Title = "KKB";
        User newUser = group.Users.Add(userCreationInfo);

        group.Update();

        clientContext.Load(newUser);
        clientContext.Load(group, grp => grp.Users);

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The Owner group setting, "Who can edit the membership of the group?" is set to "Group Members".

But when I'm executing the code I'm getting the following error:

Error Log:

```
                 05/16/2015 15:42:51.01     w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x2BBC Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Application Authentication Pipeline). Parent Request (POST:http://spf13:80/subsite/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery)  
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.01   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x2BBC Claims Authentication           ah25l   Medium      SPJsonWebSecurityBaseTokenHandler: ValidateActorIsSelfIssuer! Issuer 'High.Trust.Token.Issuer' is not self issuer.  
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.01   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x2BBC Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Getting Site Subscription Id). Parent [S2S] Getting token from STS and setting Thread Identity    
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.01   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x2BBC Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Getting Site Subscription Id). Execution Time=0.1387   
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.01   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x2BBC Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Reading token from Cache using token signature). Parent [S2S] Getting token from STS and setting Thread Identity  
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.01   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x2BBC Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Reading token from Cache using token signature). Execution Time=2.9854 
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.01   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x2BBC Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Getting Site Subscription Id). Parent [S2S] Getting token from STS and setting Thread Identity    
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.01   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x2BBC Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Getting Site Subscription Id). Execution Time=0.2525   
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.01   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x2BBC Application Authentication      ajwpw   Medium      SPApplicationAuthenticationModule: Attached actor identity to current thread. Actor Identity:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|3be7e339-20af-412e-a760-a414921dc755@0512a144-5e26-4763-9e01-474c94ef099c.  
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.01   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x2BBC Application Authentication      ahkpt   Medium      SPApplicationAuthenticationModule Authentication finished successfully for user:0#.w|dev\malag and actor:   
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.01   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x2BBC Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Application Authentication Pipeline). Execution Time=7.5725    
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.03   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x2BBC Authentication Authorization    ag6al   Medium      OAuth app principal Name=i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|3be7e339-20af-412e-a760-a414921dc755@0512a144-5e26-4763-9e01-474c94ef099c, IsAppOnlyRequest=False, UserIdentityName=0#.w|dev\malag, ClaimsCount=23    
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.03   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       agw10    Medium      Begin CSOM Request ManagedThreadId=21, NativeThreadId=5252  
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.03   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.20   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Database                        ahjqp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @        05/16/2015 15:42:51.03, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.1688 for Data Source=spf13\SharePoint;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[w3wp][2][WSS_Content] 
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.20   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Claims Authentication           aekyp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] SPSecurityTokenServiceManagerExtensions!GetProviderByName: Returning Local Issuer for input {0}    
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.22   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Authentication Authorization    ag69m   Medium      TenantScopedPerm=0, AllowAppOnlyPolicy=False, AppId=i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|3be7e339-20af-412e-a760-a414921dc755@0512a144-5e26-4763-9e01-474c94ef099c. 
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.28   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Database                        ahjqp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @        05/16/2015 15:42:51.26, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0839 for Data Source=spf13\SharePoint;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[w3wp][2][WSS_Content] 
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.28   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM Api                        agw13   High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] Leaving Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection._SerializeToJson 
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.34   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Database                        ahjqp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @        05/16/2015 15:42:51.28, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0679 for Data Source=spf13\SharePoint;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[w3wp][2][WSS_Content] 
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.34   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 General    6t8j High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] {0}    
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.56   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Database                        ahjqp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @        05/16/2015 15:42:51.36, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.1107 for Data Source=spf13\SharePoint;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[w3wp][2][WSS_Content] 
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.56   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Database                        8acb    High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: VerboseEx] Reverting to process identity    
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.64   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Database                        ahjqp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @        05/16/2015 15:42:51.56, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0847 for Data Source=spf13\SharePoint;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[w3wp][2][WSS_Content] 
   05/16/2015 15:42:51.64   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Database                        8acb    High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: VerboseEx] Reverting to process identity    
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Database                        ahjqp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @        05/16/2015 15:42:51.64, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.1392 for Data Source=spf13\SharePoint;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[w3wp][2][WSS_Content] 
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (SPSqlClient). Execution Time=803.4345  
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 General    8e2s Medium      Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005  
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 General    aix9j    High        SPRequest.UpdateMembers: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-4262198823-3978964446-1445786758-1106, AppPrincipalName=I:0I.T|MS.SP.EXT|3BE7E339-20AF-412E-A760-A414921DC755@0512A144-5E26-4763-9E01-474C94EF099C ,bstrUrl=http://spf13/SubSite ,dwObjectType=0 ,bstrObjId= ,lGroupID=6 ,lGroupOwnerId=5 ,bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly=False ,bSendEmail=True    
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 General    ai1wu    Medium      System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.UpdateMembers(Object objUpdateInfo, Object objAddIds, Object objRemoveLogins, Object objRemoveIds, Boolean fSendEmail)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.AddCollection(SPUserInfo[] addUsersInfo, IEnumerable`1 addUsers)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.Add(SPUserCreationInformation parameters)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPUserCollectionServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext... 
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 General    ai1wu    Medium      ... proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeMethod(Object obj, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.GetObjectFromObjectPath(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.GetObjectFromObjectPathId(String objectPathId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessInstantiateObjectPath(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.Process()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestServiceImpl.ProcessQuery(Stream inpu...  
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 General    ai1wu    Medium      ...tStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestService.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream)     at SyncInvokeProcessQuery(Object , Object[] , Object[] )     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThr...  
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 General    ai1wu    Medium      ...ead, OperationContext currentOperationContext)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)     at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)     at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)     at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)     at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)     at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType ite...  
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 General    ai1wu    Medium      ...m, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result)     at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult result)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, ...  
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 General    ai1wu    Medium      ...Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)     at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()     at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()     at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)     at System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)     at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapp...  
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 General    ai1wu    Medium      ...ed)     at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)     at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)      
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       ahjq1    High        Exception occured in scope Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.Add. Exception=System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateMembers(String bstrUrl, UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32 lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object& pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object& pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean bSendEmail)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.UpdateMembers(Object objUpdateInfo, Object objAddIds, Object objRemoveLogins, Object objRemoveIds, Boolean fSendEmail)     at Mic... 
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       ahjq1    High        ...rosoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.AddCollection(SPUserInfo[] addUsersInfo, IEnumerable`1 addUsers)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.Add(SPUserCreationInformation parameters)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPUserCollectionServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)    
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       agmjp    High        Original error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateMembers(String bstrUrl, UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32 lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object& pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object& pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean bSendEmail)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.UpdateMembers(Object objUpdateInfo, Object objAddIds, Object objRemoveLogins, Object objRemoveIds, Boolean fSendEmail)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.AddCollection(SPUserInfo[] ad... 
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       agmjp    High        ...dUsersInfo, IEnumerable`1 addUsers)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.Add(SPUserCreationInformation parameters)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPUserCollectionServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)    
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Authentication Authorization    alkvd   Medium      Throw UnauthorizedAccessException instead of SPUtilityInternal.Send401 for client.svc request.  
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.Add). Execution Time=890.9389    
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       agmjp    High        Original error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateMembers(String bstrUrl, UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32 lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object& pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object& pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean bSendEmail)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.UpdateMembers(Object objUpdateInfo, Object objAddIds, Object objRemoveLogins, Object objRemoveIds, Boolean fSendEmail)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.AddCollection(SPUserInfo[] ad... 
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       agmjp    High        ...dUsersInfo, IEnumerable`1 addUsers)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.Add(SPUserCreationInformation parameters)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPUserCollectionServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeMethod(Object obj, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.GetObjectFromObjectPath(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.GetObjectFromObjectPathId(Strin...  
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       agmjp    High        ...g objectPathId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessInstantiateObjectPath(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.Process()    
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 Authentication Authorization    alkvd   Medium      Throw UnauthorizedAccessException instead of SPUtilityInternal.Send401 for client.svc request.  
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       afxv7    High        System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateMembers(String bstrUrl, UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32 lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object& pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object& pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean bSendEmail)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.UpdateMembers(Object objUpdateInfo, Object objAddIds, Object objRemoveLogins, Object objRemoveIds, Boolean fSendEmail)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.AddCollection(SPUserInfo[] addUsersInfo, IEnu... 
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       afxv7    High        ...merable`1 addUsers)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.Add(SPUserCreationInformation parameters)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPUserCollectionServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeMethod(Object obj, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.GetObjectFromObjectPath(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.GetObjectFromObjectPathId(String objectPathId) ...  
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       afxv7    High        ...    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessInstantiateObjectPath(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.Process()    
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       aiv4i    High        RequestMessage: <Request AddExpandoFieldTypeSuffix="true" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="15.0.0.0" ApplicationName=".NET Library" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009"><Actions><ObjectPath Id="2" ObjectPathId="1" /><ObjectPath Id="4" ObjectPathId="3" /><Query Id="5" ObjectPathId="3"><Query SelectAllProperties="true"><Properties /></Query></Query><ObjectPath Id="7" ObjectPathId="6" /><ObjectPath Id="9" ObjectPathId="8" /><ObjectIdentityQuery Id="10" ObjectPathId="8" /><Query Id="11" ObjectPathId="8"><Query SelectAllProperties="false"><Properties><Property Name="Users" SelectAll="true"><Query SelectAllProperties="false"><Properties /></Query></Property></Properties></Query></Query><ObjectPath Id="14" ObjectPathId="13" /><ObjectPath Id="16" ObjectPathId="1... 
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       aiv4i    High        ...5" /><ObjectIdentityQuery Id="17" ObjectPathId="15" /><Method Name="Update" Id="18" ObjectPathId="8" /><Query Id="19" ObjectPathId="15"><Query SelectAllProperties="true"><Properties><Property Name="Email" ScalarProperty="true" /><Property Name="LoginName" ScalarProperty="true" /><Property Name="Title" ScalarProperty="true" /></Properties></Query></Query><Query Id="20" ObjectPathId="8"><Query SelectAllProperties="false"><Properties><Property Name="Users" SelectAll="true"><Query SelectAllProperties="false"><Properties /></Query></Property></Properties></Query></Query></Actions><ObjectPaths><StaticProperty Id="1" TypeId="{3747adcd-a3c3-41b9-bfab-4a64dd2f1e0a}" Name="Current" /><Property Id="3" ParentId="1" Name="Web" /><Property Id="6" ParentId="3" Name="SiteGroups" /><Method Id="8" ParentId=...  
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       aiv4i    High        ..."6" Name="GetById"><Parameters><Parameter Type="Int32">6</Parameter></Parameters></Method><Property Id="13" ParentId="8" Name="Users" /><Method Id="15" ParentId="13" Name="Add"><Parameters><Parameter TypeId="{6ecd8af6-bed3-4a74-be76-1ec981b350e1}"><Property Name="Email" Type="kkb@dev.com" /><Property Name="LoginName" Type="String">dev\kkb</Property><Property Name="Title" Type="String">KKB</Property></Parameter></Parameters></Method></ObjectPaths></Request> 
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       agmjp    High        Original error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateMembers(String bstrUrl, UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32 lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object& pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object& pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean bSendEmail)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.UpdateMembers(Object objUpdateInfo, Object objAddIds, Object objRemoveLogins, Object objRemoveIds, Boolean fSendEmail)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.AddCollection(SPUserInfo[] ad... 
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       agmjp    High        ...dUsersInfo, IEnumerable`1 addUsers)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.Add(SPUserCreationInformation parameters)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPUserCollectionServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeMethod(Object obj, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.GetObjectFromObjectPath(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.GetObjectFromObjectPathId(Strin...  
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17*  w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x1484 CSOM       agmjp    High        ...g objectPathId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessInstantiateObjectPath(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.Process()    
   05/16/2015 15:42:52.17   w3wp.exe (0x28E0)    0x2BBC Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://spf13:80/subsite/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery)). Execution Time=1157.1803
```

Comment: Could you please share the content of AppManifest.xml file? Especially  AppPermissionRequests section.